# How can I delete 4 Million Leases in my Hashicorp Vault

Tags: amazon-s3, hashicorp-vault

I am running Hashicorp Vault Version 0.11.5 on an m4-4Xlarge instance with 16 CPUs and 64 GiB memory. I am NOT running a Vault Cluster. I see that the Vault goes out of memory every 3 hours. I am using S3 as a backend. When I try to bring up the leases using Vault admin UI, the response times out and I get to see nothing on the UI. I tried doing CURL in the local machine but the using the /sys/leases/lookup/auth/userpass/login/myusername endpoint, the request times out and nothing is shown.

I tried to list the number of objects in the S3 Bucket for the Vault. I see that under the S3 bucket prefix sys/expire/id/auth/userpass/login/ there are 4 million lease objects listed. There are 300 users and 4 Million leases of which most of the leases are going to expire in 30 days.

1. How can I delete these 4Million leases?
2. Is there a way to profile Hashicorp Vault while it is running? Can I know why the Vault goes out of memory?
3. What will happen if I write a script to delete the objects in S3 under the prefix: sys/expire/id/auth/userpass/login/?
4. What are side effects of doing the above and
5. How can I be safe so as to not to do anything destructive on the Vault which is running in Production?
6. Could it be a case were Vault recursively loads the leases and goes into an infinite loop? How to debug this?

I tried to write a batch script which will revoke leases and I also tried to do force revoke leases. However, it does not seem to work. The leases are still there and they are old leases which got created about 30 days ago.
I tried to delete the leases for specific users in the Vault admin UI but the UI does not show.
We now changed the default configuration to expire leases after 2 minutes but that will ensure that new leases are short lived. THe existing leases are having an expiration time of 32 days.

/usr/local/bin/vault lease revoke -force  -prefix auth/userpass/login/"$line"/ >> output_lease_revoke.log

There is no error message in the output of the log file. Also, the Vault Admin UI shows now error when doing a revoke lease or force revoke lease.

Comment: hi did u managed to find any solutions ?

Comment: @johnjerrico We did two things:We set the expiration time to 2 minutes, and we found that there was a bug in the script which revoked the leases. We fixed the script. After a few days the long lived leases got cleared up and the problem got resolved.

Comment: How do we set the expiration time to 2 minutes @stalwalk ?  can you please opensource the script if possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With vault 1.15 there is the revoke by prefix command:

https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/docs/commands/lease/revoke

```
vault lease revoke -prefix database/creds
```

> -prefix (bool: false) - Treat the ID as a prefix instead of an exact lease ID. This can revoke multiple leases simultaneously. The default
> is false.